# Access Plugin data from Functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function

I'm trying to insert data from a wordpress post into a new table database table rather than `WP_postmeta`. My function is working, It'll insert the `$postid` no problem at all. The issues I'm having is I need to inser the latitude and longitude coordinates from Marty Spellerbergs 'Address Geocoder' Plugin.

On the plugin page which can be seen here https://wordpress.org/plugins/address-geocoder/, Marty says you can access the cooridnates inside the loop using these:

```
<?php echo get_geocode_lng( $post->ID ); ?>
<?php echo get_geocode_lat( $post->ID ); ?>
```

Now I know being inside the functions.php file, we are not actually inside the lood, so I've tried lots of different ways of accessing this data but I just can't do it. Is there a way to edit those lines specified by Marty so they can be called in the functions?.

This is one of my many many attempts at this:

```
function save_lat_lng( $post_id )   
{  
    global $wpdb;  

global $post;
$custom_lat = $_POST[get_geocode_lat( $post->ID )]; 
$custom_lng = $_POST[get_geocode_lng( $post->ID )];
// Check that we are editing the right post type  
if ( 'festival-event' != $_POST['post_type'] ) 
{  
    return;  
}  

// Check if we have a lat/lng stored for this property already  
$check_link = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM lat_lng_post WHERE post_id = '" . $post_id . "'");  
if ($check_link != null)   
{  
    // We already have a lat lng for this post. Update row  
    $wpdb->update(   
    'lat_lng_post',   
    array(   
        "lat" => $custom_lat,
        "lng" => $custom_lng 
    ),   
    array( 'post_id' => $post_id ),   
    array(   
        '%f',  
        '%f'  
    )  
    );  
}  
else  
{  
    // We do not already have a lat lng for this post. Insert row  
    $wpdb->insert(   
    'lat_lng_post',   
    array(   
        'post_id' => $post_id,  
        "lat" => $custom_lat,
        "lng" => $custom_lng
    ),   
    array(   
        '%d',   
        '%f',  
        '%f'  
    )   
    );  
}  
}  
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_lat_lng' )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are passing `post_id` as parameter to function save_lat_lng i think that you should change that two lines:

```
$custom_lat = $_POST[get_geocode_lat( $post->ID )]; 
$custom_lng = $_POST[get_geocode_lng( $post->ID )];
```

to

```
$custom_lat = get_geocode_lat( $post_id ); 
$custom_lng = get_geocode_lng( $post_id );
```

to access that parameters.

also if you want to check post type you should change

```
if ( 'festival-event' != $_POST['post_type'] )
```

to

```
if ( 'festival-event' != get_post_type($post_id) )
```

docs below:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type

PS. next time you should paste link for plugin, it saves time :)

**--- UPDATE**

Coordinates were not available - problem was related to save_post hook priority value.

From plugin code i see that function updating post meta have that priority:

```
add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );
```

so to run your hook after that, you should set something like that:

`add_action( 'save_post', 'save_lat_lng', 100 );`

Comment: Unfortunately that hasn't worked, however I appreciate the attempt. Sorry I'll edit the post with a link for future

Comment: so what return values do you have for variables custom_lat and custom_lng?

Comment: In the Wordpress Backend they are set as Latitude and Longitude Coordinates. These are already used in the look with the code I gave above to place markers on the map

Comment: if you are using that function on save_post it means that plugin didn't store already that information and they are not available from function get_geocode_lat and get_geocode_lng.

From plugin code i see that function updating post meta have that priority:

`add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'save_post' ), 10, 2 );`

so to run your hook after that, you should set something like that:

`add_action( 'save_post', 'save_lat_lng', 100 );`

see [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Parameters)

Comment: returns this when i debug `Notice: Undefined index: 50.71081239999999 in /home/beafweb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BEAF/functions.php on line 49

Notice: Undefined index: -1.9940134999999373 in /home/beafweb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BEAF/functions.php on line 50`